# lightopenid does not post session variable(s)

Tags: php, yii, yii2, openid

Currently working on a shoutbox, and using LightOpenID to provide a Steam log in method. I am also using the Yii2 framework. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Below is index.php, which posts data according to SteamID.

```
<?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $form yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm */
/* @var $model app\models\LoginForm */

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;

$this->title = 'Dashboard';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;

require "steamauth/steamauth.php";

if(!isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) {

    echo('Hitting no steamid marker');

    $localUserName = "Guest";

    }  else {

    include ('steamauth/userInfo.php');

    $localUserName = ucfirst($_SESSION['steam_personaname']);
    };

if (!isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) {
    echo ("<div class='well'>
    <div class='jumbotron'>
    <h1>Login here.</h1>
    <p>This prevents x from having to store user passwords. Powered by <a href='http://www.steampowered.com'><strong>STEAM</strong></a>.</p>
    <p><a id='steamlogin' href='?r=user-record/index&login=1' class='btn btn-success btn-large loginButton'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-log-in'></span> Login through Steam</a></p>
    </div>
    </div>");
    $this->title = 'Login';

} else { 

    echo("
        <div class='well'>
        <div class='jumbotron'>
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        <p>Hey there, <a href=". $_SESSION['steam_profileurl'] . "><strong>" . $_SESSION['steam_personaname'] . "</strong></a>. </p>
        <p><img src=" . $_SESSION['steam_avatarfull'] . "</img></p>
        <p>Steam ID: <strong>" . $_SESSION['steamid'] . "</strong></p>


        <p>
        <p><a id='steamlogout' href='?r=user-record/index&logout=1' class='btn btn-danger btn-large logoutButton'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-log-out'></span> Disconnect</a></p>
        </div>
        </div>");
}
?>
```

This is the authorization file, which makes it all the way to returning the authURL but then proceeds to redirect back to the login page without any variables set. Expecting for it to return 'steamid'.

```
ob_start();
if (isset($_GET['login'])){
    require 'openid.php';
    echo('login initiated');
    try {
        echo('try initiiated');
        require 'SteamConfig.php';
        $openid = new LightOpenID($steamauth['domainname']);

        if(!$openid->mode) {
            $openid->identity = 'http://steamcommunity.com/openid';
            return Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect($openid->authUrl());
        } elseif ($openid->mode == 'cancel') {
            echo 'User has canceled authentication!';
        } else {
            if($openid->validate()) { 
                echo("reached validation");
                $id = $openid->identity;
                $ptn = '/^http:\/\/steamcommunity\.com\/openid\/id\/(7[0-9]{15,25}+)$/';
                preg_match($ptn, $id, $matches);

                $_SESSION['steamid'] = $matches[1];
                if (!headers_sent()) {
                    header('Location: '.$steamauth['loginpage']);
                    exit;
                } else {
                    ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        window.location.href="<?=$steamauth['loginpage']?>";
                    </script>
                    <noscript>
                        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=<?=$steamauth['loginpage']?>" />
                    </noscript>
                    <?php
                    exit;
                }
            } else {
                echo "User is not logged in.\n";
            }
        }
    } catch(ErrorException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you start the session inside all files using them?

Comment: was as simple as that. wow. thank you.

Comment: you're welcome. I popped an answer down there for you if you wish to mark it as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start the session inside all files using sessions with `session_start();` at the top of your files.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Error reporting would have helped you also:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php